# Python Web Scraping ESPN team Rosters

Tags: python, web-scraping, espn

I have this code to scrape the Player information (Name, Position, Number) by pasting in a URL from 'any' ESPN Roster page.  I say 'any' because any page that has at least one player without a number/jersey value errors out.  Is there a way to fix such an error.

As an example of each, the Philadelphia Eagles page converts correctly (https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/roster/_/name/phi)
But the Detroit Lions roster does not (https://www.espn.com/nfl/team/roster/_/name/det)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, json, re
import requests

team = ''
def SavePlayerData(DATA):
    global team
    for s in ['\\','/',':','*','?','"','<','>','|']:
        team = team.replace(s,'')
    outfilename = '%s.txt'%(team)
    with open(outfilename, 'w') as out_file:
        for line in DATA:
            out_file.write(line)

def GetTeamData(link):
    global opener, headers, team, short

    response = opener.get(link,headers=headers).text.encode('utf-8')

    content = re.search("window\['__espnfitt__'\]\=(.+?)\;</script>",response).group(1)

    jsonobj = json.loads(content)
    roster = jsonobj['page']['content']['roster']

    team = roster['team']['displayName']
    coach = roster['coach']['description']

    TEAM = []
    for group in roster['groups']:
        for player in group['athletes']:
            n=player['name']
            p=player['position']
            j=player['jersey']
            DATA = '%s%s\t%s %s %s (%s)\t[%s]\n'%(short,j,team,p,n,j,n)
            TEAM.append(DATA)

    DATA = '%shc\t%s %s %s\t[%s]\n'%(short,team,'head coach',coach,coach)
    TEAM.append(DATA)
    SavePlayerData(TEAM)
opener = requests.Session()
headers = {'host': 'www.espn.com',
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}

if __name__=="__main__":

    teamURL = raw_input(' >> Enter the Team Roster URL :: ').strip()

    short = raw_input(' >> Enter the Letter for this Team :: ').strip().lower()
    if not short:
        short='d'

    try:
        if not teamURL:
            raise Exception

        if not '/roster/' in teamURL:
            teamURL = teamURL.replace('/team/_/','/team/roster/_/')

        print ('\n >> Collecting Data from <%s>\n'%(teamURL))
        GetTeamData(teamURL)
        print (' >> Link Scraped & Data Saved to File')

    except Exception as e:
        print ('\n >> Failed to Get Required Data, Re-Check your Input URL.')
```

Comment: maybe you forgot to share a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the try/except, or just put in a conditional statement to check if the jersey is in the data:

```
import os, json, re
import requests

team = ''
def SavePlayerData(DATA):
    global team
    for s in ['\\','/',':','*','?','"','<','>','|']:
        team = team.replace(s,'')
    outfilename = '%s.txt'%(team)
    with open(outfilename, 'w') as out_file:
        for line in DATA:
            out_file.write(line)

def GetTeamData(link):
    global opener, headers, team, short

    response = opener.get(link,headers=headers).text

    content = re.search("window\['__espnfitt__'\]\=(.+?)\;</script>",response).group(1)

    jsonobj = json.loads(content)
    roster = jsonobj['page']['content']['roster']

    team = roster['team']['displayName']
    coach = roster['coach']['description']

    TEAM = []
    for group in roster['groups']:
        for player in group['athletes']:
            n=player['name']
            p=player['position']
            if 'jersey' in player:
                j=player['jersey']
            else:
                j = ''
            DATA = '%s%s\t%s %s %s (%s)\t[%s]\n'%(short,j,team,p,n,j,n)
            TEAM.append(DATA)

    DATA = '%shc\t%s %s %s\t[%s]\n'%(short,team,'head coach',coach,coach)
    TEAM.append(DATA)
    SavePlayerData(TEAM)
opener = requests.Session()
headers = {'host': 'www.espn.com',
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}

if __name__=="__main__":

    teamURL = input(' >> Enter the Team Roster URL :: ').strip()

    short = input(' >> Enter the Letter for this Team :: ').strip().lower()
    if not short:
        short='d'

    try:
        if not teamURL:
            raise Exception

        if not '/roster/' in teamURL:
            teamURL = teamURL.replace('/team/_/','/team/roster/_/')

        print ('\n >> Collecting Data from <%s>\n'%(teamURL))
        GetTeamData(teamURL)
        print (' >> Link Scraped & Data Saved to File')

    except Exception as e:
        print ('\n >> Failed to Get Required Data, Re-Check your Input URL.')
```